# How to change hazelcast cache refresh

Tags: hazelcast

We have a [hazelcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazelcast) problem. For the last few days, it has not been refreshing itself. We have to maunally refresh the cache from the web console.

What can I do about this?

And other problem is: How can I force hazelcast to read from db if cache does not exist?

Comment: Have you tried change the version of .js ans .css?

Comment: What does "refresh" mean for you?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean by Refresh. Normally, what users do is, they have TTL configured for the entries in MAP. And you can also implement a MapStore that will read from DB, when entry is not available in cache. When your applications read the entry and if it doesn't exist in cache, Hazelcast will call the mapstore to read from DB. And after TTL elapsed, the entry will be removed from the cache. Next time you read it, it will be refreshed.